# ImportError: No module named _binary

Tags: python, django

For some reason, my Django server refuses to start, giving me the error `ImportError: No module named _binary`. I have since upgraded and reinstalled most of the python and Django stack I'm using, but have had little luck in locating the cause of the error.

The server has been working just fine until quite recently, and it does work fine on other workstations (one of which mirrors my OSX Mountain Lion workstation more or less identically).

I have no idea what might have caused this error to occur, nor do I know where to find more information on plausible perpetrators. Can anyone of you help me?

Comment: Have you searched your code (including third-party modules you're using) for `import _binary` and `from _binary`?

Comment: No hits for either query.

Comment: Don't you get a stack trace telling you what code tries to import (from) `_binary`?

Comment: Seems to me the error might be related to PIL / Pillow: https://www.pythonanywhere.com/forums/topic/578/

Comment: I've stumbled across that forum post earlier, but after uninstalling/reinstalling PIL the error prevails. Without any stack traces.

Comment: How about uninstalling PIL, and not reinstalling it? If necessary, eliminate dependencies on PIL to see if that's the problem.

Comment: I finally found the culprit: an error in my PATH variables. Would not have found it if it weren't for me searching for the error in my PIL install, so thanks anyway :)